# Dyanmic change button postback url asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, postbackurl

is it possible to dynamic changing a button post back url property? For example I got 3 page which is `salesListing.aspx`, `orderlisting.aspx` and `createDetail.aspx`.

The `salesListing` and `orderlisting` allow user to navigate to `createDetail` page. However in the `createDetail.aspx` I got a back button.

Is it possible the back button can detect which pages cause the postback? And, when user click the back button, the back button will save record and bring it back to the previous page?

For example 
user click orderlisting then click createDetail page. when he click the back button , the back button save user id and  bring user back to the orderlisting .

Answer (score 0):

You can use Link button and if you are using master page then assign relevant Navigation URL according to which page are at.
Like you have a link button

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink8" NavigateUrl="Login.aspx"
                            runat="server">Login</asp:HyperLink>
```

And in code behind you can change its URL.

```
if (Session["User"] != null)
{
    HyperLink8.Text = "Logout";
    HyperLink8.NavigateUrl = "Logout.aspx";
}
else
{
    HyperLink8.Text = "Login";
    HyperLink8.NavigateUrl = "Login.aspx";
}
```

Comment: how about a button?Not hyperlink?

Comment: for button you can use javascript and also you can code behind. but for back javascript is better. onclick="javascript: history.go(-1);

Answer (score 0):

I've written a project that will manage all that back navigation for you automatically, http://navigation.codeplex.com/.

You configure your pages as a list of states. Below each state are the possible transitions to different states. For example, your configuration would be:

```
<state key="sales" page="~/salesListing.aspx">
    <transition key="next" to="create"/>
</state>
<state key="order" page="~/orderListing.aspx">
    <transition key="next" to="create"/>
</state>
<state key="create" page="~/createDetail.aspx"/>
```

Then in code, to move from salesListing to createDetail you write:

```
StateController.Navigate("Next");
```

And to go back from createDetail to salesListing you write:

```
StateController.NavigateBack(1);
```

If you're interested or want any help, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

An option would just be to use the javascript `history` object.

On your button, put the code `OnClientClick="javascript: history.go(-1); return false;"`

This will just go to the previous page.

```
<asp:Button id="btnClick" runat="Server" text="Back" OnClientClick="javascript: history.go(-1); return false;" />
```

Comment: Hi, in my btnclick . i may do some function . for example save data and return back to the previous page. Is it possible ?

Comment: That isn't really changing the postback then, but doing a `Response.Redirect` after posting back to the same page to save the data.

Answer (score 0):

use `Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();` and store it on the first page load.

```
if( !IsPostBack )
```

`{
 ViewState["PreviousPageUrl"] = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
}`

After redirecting to 2nd page and if you want to go back

get the `ViewState["PreviousPageUrl"]` value and go back using `Response.Redirect(ViewState["PreviousPageUrl"].ToString())`

Answer (score 0):

Use normal html button and add history.back() function.

<input type="button" Value="Back" onClick="History.back();">

This will work on all the browsers and no server side code/ Postback required.

Happy Coding!!!